Asymptotics on sum of product of binomial coefficients
I'm interested in the behavior of the summation
$$S(a,b)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{a-k}{k}\binom{b}{k}.$$
For a fixed $\delta>0$, I would like asymptotic bounds on $S(a,\delta a)$.
With $\delta=1$, this is OEIS A002426, and the sum is
$$S(a,a)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{a-k}{k}\binom{a}{k}\sim \frac{\sqrt{3/\pi}}{2}\frac{3^a}{\sqrt{a}},$$
according to the OEIS page. I'm not quite sure how this was derived.
One should note that Wolfram Alpha gives $S$ in terms of the hypergeometric function:
$$S(a,b)={}_3F_2\left(\frac{1-a}{2}, -\frac{a}{2}, -b; 1,-a;4\right),$$
so perhaps one can pull known results about these functions.

Set $k=ax$ and look at the largest term: it gives you a cubic equation in $x$ (except when $\delta=1$ where it is simpler) and proceed from there.

What are $a$ and $b$? Are they positive integers? If so, what is $\delta a$ for an arbitrary $\delta>0$?

The case $a=b$ is the constant term in $(1+x+1/x)^a$, which is an easy local limit question (think of $a$ independent copies of a random variable with equal weights at $-1$, $0$ and $1$).

Such sums may be approximated by using the local central limit theorem.
Note that ${a-k\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{a-2k}$ and ${b\choose k}q^k(1-q)^{b-k}$, where $p,q\in [0,1]$ are binomial probabilities. In particular, they do not exceed 1, and therefore we have
$$
{a-k\choose k}{b\choose k}\leqslant p^{-k}(1-p)^{2k-a}q^{-k}(1-q)^{k-b}. \tag{1}
$$
This expression in RHS of (1) depends on $k$, but the optimal bound is achieved when it does not depend on $k$ (otherwise it is monotone in $k$, but normally the maximum should be achieved somewhere in the middle), that is, $$(1-p)^2(1-q)=pq.\tag{2}$$
Next, law of large numbers tells us that (1) is less or more sharp when $p:(1-p)\approx k:(a-2k)$ and $q:(1-q)\approx k:(b-k)$. So, $a/k-2\approx 1/p-1$ and $b/k-1\approx 1/q-1$. thus, if $b\approx \delta a$, we get another equation $$\delta(1/p+1)=1/q.\tag{3}$$
Equations (2) and (3) give a cubic equation for $p$:
$$
(1-p)^2(\delta(1/p+1)-1)=p.\tag{4}
$$
(4) reads as $$f(p):=\frac{p-p^2+p^3}{(1-p)^2(1+p)}=\delta.
\tag{5}$$
When $p$ goes from 0 to 1, $f(p)$ increases from 0 to infinity, thus (5) has unique root $p=p_\delta\in (0,1)$ for every $\delta\in (0,\infty)$. For this $p$ and $q$ defined by (3), both (2) and (3) hold, thus $0<q<1$, and for these $p,q$ and $k$ satisfying $p:(1-p)\approx k:(a-2k)$ we automatically have $q:(1-q)\approx k:(b-k)$, and (1) is sharp up to a factor of $O(\sqrt{a\cdot b})$. So, the logarithm of your sum grows is $$-a\log(1-p)-b\log(1-q)+O(\log a).$$
For more sharp asymptotics, we approximate the ratio of LHS and RHS of (1) (note that now RHS of (1) does not depend on $k$) by central limit theorem, and then replace as um by integral. You may see more details, for example, in this recent answer to a similar question I have learnt about such approach from the authors of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.02567 where it is applied to certain binomial sums
